# How to format text of site subtitle

Tags: customization, css

How do I italicise a word in the subtitle of a wordpress blog? Markdown isn't supported in the tagline field in dashboard's general settings.

Comment: Where do you want to show the site subtitle in an italicized format?

Answer (score 2):

If you output the description with [`bloginfo()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/bloginfo), you can use the filter `bloginfo`.

```
add_filter( 'bloginfo', 'wpse183972_description_italic', 10, 2 );
function wpse183972_description_italic( $text, $show )
{
    if ('description' == $show) {
        $word = 'WordPress';
        $text = preg_replace( '^(' . preg_quote( $word ) . ')^', '<em>$1</em>', $text );
    }
    return $text;
}
```